# Unable to Build/Codesign after upgrading to Snow Leopard and iPhone SDK 3.0 Snow Leopard

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, osx-snow-leopard

I have no more hair to pull. Any help greatly appreciated!

Profile set to Distribution, Device 2.2.1 Distribution, as has worked in the past.

The build fails with this error:
Command  failed with exit code -1

The below section is highlighted in Build Results.

```
ProcessingProductPackaging /Users/harvey/Documents/iPhone_App_Work/Listening-Hiragana/iPhone_Comprehension_timer_harvey/entitlements.plist "/Users/harvey/Documents/iPhone_App_Work/Listening-Hiragana/iPhone_Comprehension_timer_harvey/build/iPhone_Comprehension.build/Distribution-iphoneos/Kana Listening.build/iPhone_Comprehension.xcent"
cd /Users/harvey/Documents/iPhone_App_Work/Listening-Hiragana/iPhone_Comprehension_timer_harvey
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
<com.apple.tools.product-pkg-utility> /Users/harvey/Documents/iPhone_App_Work/Listening-Hiragana/iPhone_Comprehension_timer_harvey/entitlements.plist -entitlements -format xml -o "/Users/harvey/Documents/iPhone_App_Work/Listening-Hiragana/iPhone_Comprehension_timer_harvey/build/iPhone_Comprehension.build/Distribution-iphoneos/Kana Listening.build/iPhone_Comprehension.xcent"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you install Snow Leopard, you also need to install the Snow Leopard SDK, even if you already had the most recent SDK for Leopard.

Source 1: Personal experience
Source 2: http://blog.chomperstomp.com/“command-failed-with-exit-code-1”-error-when-compiling-iphone-app-for-device-3-0-release-build/